# How can I remove an .apk from a device with adb

Tags: android, adb

one simple question. I have an APP in an android device.
How can I unistall it via adb command line?

thanks a lot.

Comment: adb uninstall com.blablabla.app

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
adb uninstall com.company.apppackage
```

Answer (score 4):

Run `adb uninstall ...`, where `...` is your application ID.

By default, the application ID is the same as the `package` attribute on your `<manifest>` element in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, though your `build.gradle` file might override that to have a different application ID.

Comment: if I don't have the source code, how can I find out the application ID?

Comment: You can list the installed applciaitons with `adb shell 'pm list packages -f'`and find the one you want to remove.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to uninstall when connected to single device/emulator

```
adb uninstall <package name>
```

else with multiple devices

```
adb -s <device ID> uninstall <package name>
```